# Using new with decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

```
T *t; //T is an implementation detail
t = new T; //want to avoid naming T to allow for flexibility
t = new decltype(*t); //error: cannot use 'new' to allocate a reference
t = new std::remove_reference<decltype(*t)>::type(); //clunky
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242295/3484570) answers why `decltype(*t)` returns `T &` and not `T`.

I can put my last line into a macro, but that seems suboptimal.
Is there a better solution than what I have so far? Does this belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: +1, This certainly belongs to SO.

Comment: The question as to whether this belongs on Code Review or not belongs on Meta. :)

Comment: In C++11 you shouldn't be working with raw pointers.  Use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).  Don't write `new` either, implement your own [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) (or use a compiler like GCC 4.9 or the lastest MSVC++ that already have it) and use that.

Comment: The common approach to avoid naming `T` is to provide an appropriate `typedef` that can be adjusted by the library owner. I don't see the point of *hiding* types everywhere... then again I don't believe in the *almost always auto* preaching.

Comment: Actually, in isolation, `*t` _is_ a `T` :) You get an lvalue back and it's not a reference. `decltype` ruins that for you though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If they're on the same line, you can use `auto` to only name `T` once:

```
auto t = new T;
```

Otherwise, you could create a small function template:

```
template <class T>
void do_new(T * &p) {
  p = new T;
}


// Usage:
int main()
{
  T *t;
  do_new(t);
}
```

As @MadScienceDreams pointed out, you can extend this to allow non-default constructors:

```
template <class T, class... Arg>
void do_new(T * &p, Arg &&... arg) {
  p = new T(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);
}


// Usage:
int main()
{
  T *t;
  do_new(t);
  std::string *s;
  do_new(s, "Abc");
}
```

Comment: Nifty. I'd go ahead an make "do_new" a variadic template so new can have arguments.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Done. I assume you meant arguments to the constructor and not to the allocation function :-)

Answer (score 6):

`std::remove_pointer<decltype(t)>::type` is more expressive/clear.

You can also use a local `typedef` if this is repeated several times, or would make a certain line grow excessively long/complicated.