# C++: Why decltype (*this) returns a reference?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

```
template<typename T>
struct foo{
    void f(){
        decltype(*this) a(*this);
        do_some_test(a);
    }
    T data;
};
//compiler won't accept this
```

In my interpretation, `decltype` should return the a type so that we can use it in declaration. But google says that in `decltype(x)`,if `x` is a lvalue, it will return `T&` where `T` is the type of x.

But what they designed it to return a reference for? Furthermore, what should I do to create a instance of the class that has the same type as `*this` in a template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++, what expressions yield a reference type when decltype is applied to them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241614/in-c-what-expressions-yield-a-reference-type-when-decltype-is-applied-to-them)

Comment: There's also this question which talks about how to create a new instance with decltype [Using new with decltype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309356/using-new-with-decltype)

Comment: *"But what they designed it to return a reference for?"* Every expression has a value category (lvalue, xvalue or prvalue). `decltype` reflects that property by applying reference qualifers: an lvalue-reference qualifier for lvalue-expressions, an rvalue-ref for xvalues and no reference for prvalues.

Comment: Yes,[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309356/using-new-with-decltype) should be an answer. Apologize for duplication.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`decltype` deduces the type of **expression**, unless it is applied to a variable, in which case it deduces the type of that variable:

> The type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> — if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access, `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
>
> — otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
>
> — otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
>
> — otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.
>
> §7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple]

Dereferencing a pointer yields an lvalue, and therefore `decltype` will deduce an lvalue reference to the type of the pointee:

> The unary `*` operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points.
>
> §5.3.1 [expr.unary.op]

Therefore `decltype(*p)`, for some pointer `p`, deduces an lvalue reference to the type of the pointee.

If you wish to get the type of the pointee from some pointer `p`, you can use:

```
std::remove_pointer<decltype(p)>::type
```

Or:

```
std::remove_reference<decltype(*p)>::type
```

Or, in your example, you can simply say `foo`, type deduction is not required.

Comment: or in c++14 you can directly use std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*p)>, no need for verbose std::remove_reference<decltype(*p)>::type