# User defined type trait gives an unexpected false type

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

**Printing string that contains type info:**

```cpp
std::string demangle(const char* mangled_name) {
        size_t len = 0;
        int status = 0;

        std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(&std::free)> pointer (
            __cxxabiv1::__cxa_demangle(mangled_name, nullptr, &len, &status),
            &std::free);

        return pointer.get();
}

template <typename T>
std::string type_of(const T& arg) {
     return demangle(typeid(arg).name());
}
```

**My custom `is_string` type trait:**

```cpp
template <typename T> struct is_string : std::false_type {};
template <> struct is_string<char*> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct is_string<char[]> : std::true_type {};
template <size_t N> struct is_string<char[N]> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct is_string<const char*> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct is_string<const char[]> : std::true_type {};
template <size_t N> struct is_string<const char[N]> : std::true_type {};

// Helper variable:
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_string_v = is_string<T>::value;
```

**Application:**

```cpp
std::cout << std::boolalpha;

std::cout << "Testing: " << '\n'
    << "char* = " << is_string_v<char*> << '\n'
    << "char[] = " << is_string_v<char[]> << '\n'
    << "char[10] = " << is_string_v<char[10]> << '\n'
    << "char[15] = " << is_string_v<char[15]> << '\n'
    << "const char* = " << is_string_v<const char*> << '\n'
    << "const char[] = " << is_string_v<const char[]> << '\n'
    << "const char[3] = " << is_string_v<const char[3]> << '\n'
    << "const char[6] = " << is_string_v<const char[6]> << "\n\n";

const char* string1 = "Hello";
const char string2[] = "Hello";
char string3[] = "Hello";
auto string4 = "Hello";

std::cout << "Testing with decltype(variable): " << '\n'
    << type_of(string1) << " = " << is_string_v<decltype(string1)> << '\n'
    << type_of(string2) << " = " << is_string_v<decltype(string2)> << '\n'
    << type_of(string3) << " = " << is_string_v<decltype(string3)> << '\n'
    << type_of(string4) << " = " << is_string_v<decltype(string4)> << "\n\n";

std::cout << "Testing with string literal: " << '\n'
    << type_of("Hello") << " = " << is_string_v<decltype("Hello")> << '\n';
```

**Output:**

```cpp
Testing:
char* = true
char[] = true
char[10] = true
char[15] = true
const char* = true
const char[] = true
const char[3] = true
const char[6] = true

Testing with decltype(variable):
char const* = true
char [6] = true
char [6] = true
char const* = true

Testing with string literal:
char [6] = false
```

- Why is `is_string_v<decltype(some string literal)>` `false` when they have the same type as `string3` or `char [6]` which has `true` value when it passes as template parameter?
- Is there something wrong with my demangling function? (since my implementation doesn't include a reference)

Comment: Have you considered comparing the mangled strings?  Like, string3 and the quoted string?  Have you considered checking is same in the types?

Comment: i was forgotten to test out with the `is_same`. so my problem is all about having the additional references and cv-qualifiers without repeating myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << is_string_v<char const[sizeof "Hello"]> << '\n';
    std::cout << is_string_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype("Hello")>> << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
```

Looks like `decltype` added an extra reference. Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25312375/13188071):

> The type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> - if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access, `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
> - **otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;**
> - otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.
>
> §7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple]

And [string literals are lvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10004567/13188071), so it adds a reference.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is c-style string literals like `"Hello"` are an expressions, then [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) yields type as `T&`, i.e. `const char (&) [6]` for `"Hello"`. (Note that `decltype` works in two different ways for unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access expression, and any other expression.)

You can add specialization as

```
template <size_t N> struct is_string<const char(&)[N]> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: how can i do this to other `char`-like types by removing some boilerplates?

Comment: @DesmondGold What do you mean about `char`-like types? For example?

Comment: i mean such as `unsigned char(&)[N]`, `wchar_t(&)[N]`, or `char8_t(&)[N]`

Comment: @DesmondGold You have to define specializations for them respectively. Or make type trait but still need to specify all the `char`-like types explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
template<class T> struct is_string<T&>:is_string<T>{};
template<class T> struct is_string<T&&>:is_string<T>{};
template<class T> struct is_string<T const>:is_string<T>{};
template<class T> struct is_string<T volatile>:is_string<T>{};
template<class T> struct is_string<T const volatile>:is_string<T>{};
```

and remove the `const char[]` and `const char[N]` specializations.

Also you might want to support `u8` strings and wchar_t etc.