# Decltype a dereferenced pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, decltype

Can somebody explain to me why I can't do something along the lines of:

```
int* b = new int(5);
int* c = new decltype(*b)(5);

cout << *c << endl;
```

This throws C464 'int &': cannot use 'new' to allocate a reference. How would I perform doing something like this? What I need is the derefferenced base type of the variable that I send.

This works though

```
int* b = new int(5);
int** a = new int*(b);

decltype(*a) c = *a;
cout << *c<< endl;
```

I understand how the code above works but how would I perform something like that using new?

Comment: Because it is an expression [you get back a reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33601014/1708801)

Comment: new std:decay_t<decltype(*b)>(5); ?

Comment: If you follow the link, my answer there has a couple of work-arounds.

Comment: A non-ugly workaround for this particular case is `new auto`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a1fb6c0780d9bae

Comment: Just do `int *p = new auto{5};`

Comment: Thanks both, @RichardHodges that worked perfectly

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The dereference operator `*` returns a reference, which you cannot allocate using `new`. Instead you could use [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) in `<type_traits>`

```
int* b = new int(5);
int* c = new std::remove_pointer<decltype(b)>::type(5);    
std::cout << *c << std::endl;
```

Comment: Wish I've had 15+ to upvote this. I get the idea, thank you a lot!

Comment: @IlhanKarić you can accept the answer which is a reward for an answer that you find helpful.

Comment: you saved my life today !