# Why not always use std::forward?

Tags: c++, c++11

The distinction between `std::move` and `std::forward` is well known, we use the latter to preserve the value category of a forwarded object and the former to cast to rvalue reference in order to enable move semantics.

In **effective modern C++**, a guideline exists that states

> use `std::move` on rvalue references, `std::forward` on universal references.

Yet in the following scenario (*and scenarios where we don't want to change value category*),

```
template <class T>
void f(vector<T>&& a)
{
    some_func(std::move(a)); 
}
```

where `a` is not a forwarding reference but a simple rvalue reference, wouldn't it be exactly the same to do the following?

```
template <class T>
void f(vector<T>&& a)
{
    some_func(std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)); 
}
```

Since this can be easily encapsulated in a macro like this,

```
#define FWD(arg) std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg)
```

isn't it convenient to always use this macro definition like so?

```
void f(vector<T>&& a)
{
    some_func(FWD(a)); 
}
```

Aren't the two ways of writing this exactly equivalent?

Comment: I have trouble viewing the macro solution as more convenient than writing `move()`... but this strikes me as an opinion-based question. Both do the same thing

Comment: but somtimes the argument is a regular reference and you do want to move the vector. keep using forwarding doesn't accomplish that

Comment: @Barry I wanted a confirmation on them being equivalent, thnx for that. I'd like to disagree on whether they're opinion based, simply advocating on a programming style does not imply bias, one might have very good reasons to do it (and be able to elaborate on them)

Comment: @DavidHaim Yes, well I mean in cases like the one I give (where only preserving the value category is needed). I edited the question to make that more clear

Comment: Adding a macro obscures understanding. If you're doing something deliberately strange, like you're doing here, it should be *obvious* even at the expense of verbosity.

Comment: @tadman This could be a reason, but after writing move aware code for a real project I found verbosity a major deal breaker, really frustrating stuff ..

Comment: About "... wouldn't it be exactly the same to do this..." I think it is exactly the same; because vector<T>&& a is an rvalue reference, and making an unconditional cast (move) or a conditional cast (forward) to an rvalue reference makes no difference.

Comment: @LorahAttkins Verbosity is usually a sign you're going against the grain of the language which is something you can look for in a code review. If you've got all these macros to minify what you're doing you're basically inventing a dialect of C++ that's not conventional and will be harder to understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eh. Debatable. In your particular example it is equivalent. But I wouldn't make it a habit. One reason is because you want a semantic distinction between forwarding and moving. Another reason is because to have a consistent API you'd have to have `MOV` in addition to `FWD`, and that really looks bad and doesn't do anything. More importantly, though, is that your code can fail unexpectedly.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define FWD(arg) std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg)

struct S {
    S() { cout << "S()\n"; }
    S(const S&) { cout << "S(const S&)\n"; }
    S(S&&) { cout << "S(S&&)\n"; }
};

void some_func(S) {}

void f(S&& s)
{
    some_func(FWD(s)); 
}

int main()
{
    f(S{});
}
```

This prints out

> S()
>   S(S&&)

However, if I just change the `FWD` line to have another (seemingly optional) pair of parentheses, like this:

```
void f(S&& s)
{
    some_func(FWD((s))); 
}
```

Now we get

> S()
>   S(const S&)

And this is because now we're using `decltype` on an expression, which evaluates to an lvalue reference.

Comment: You make good points. But I disagree on the "seemingly optional" characterization for the parentheses. If one is working with `decltype` should know [this stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17242295/4224575) and this a mistake doable even in `std::forward<decltype...` (which is a syntax often encountered in generic lambdas), not a macro thing

Comment: @Lorah Yeah, but it's a macro - you can't immediately see that it uses `decltype`.

Comment: @Barry I guess you wouldn't see what it does if it was a function either, you always have to read the code; I mostly grasp the "lack of transparency" related to macros as "weird side-effects or mutation of the behavior" that are not obvious even when you read the code (like evaluating an expression twice etc...). I'm not above using a macro for reasons like `FWD` i.e. textual replacement (no double evaluation, no incidental data structures, no hidden control flow). Could you please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36230428/4224575) ? (it's off topic but I could use some help)

Comment: @LorahAttkins Part of the problem here is the use of decltype in the first place. It's not really needed, and it brings its bag of subtleties along with it.

Comment: @LorahAttkins I agree with you. The macro with std::forward you propose truly works (as much as anything before it). What @YamMarcovic says should be already known anyway. You could use `std::forward` for pretty much everything, unless you specifically want an rvalue cast, in which case you do an `std::move`.