# Eliminate copies when constructing members of a class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

For two arbitrary objects of type `T` and `U` that are composed into a class like so

```
template <class T, class U>
struct Comp
{
    T t_m; 
    U u_m; 
};
```

**what would be the optimum (in terms of minimizing copy operations) way to construct them out of (available) temporaries ?**

I have considered "moving" them into my class

```
Comp(T&& t, U&& u)
    : t_m(std::move(t))
    , u_m(std::move(u))
{ }
```

but I don't know how well their move constructors behave **or if they have any whatsoever**.

Since it seems that my class can be an aggregate I was wondering whether removing the constructor and allowing [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) would be a better solution, i.e. writing code like this:

```
Comp{ get_temporary_T(), get_temporary_U() };
```

or if there's an advantage in using [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

### PS

In place construction (using placement new operator) is not the solution I'm looking for.

### PS 2

I imagine `std::tuple` uses such an optimum method since [`make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) is shown to **utilize temporaries** by calling the tuple constructor :

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(10, "Test", 3.14, std::ref(n), n);
```

could alternatively someone elaborate on how this is done ?

Comment: too broad ?  "what would be the optimum (in terms of minimizing copy operations) way to construct them out of (available) temporaries ?" is too broad ?

Comment: Why not test the simplest of code with optimizations turned on first, before embarking on trying to outdo the compiler's optimizer?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could you help me on how to do this? Do you mean inspect the machine code, benchmark for speed, instrument my code?

Comment: "*I imagine std::tuple uses such an optimum method since make_tuple is shown to utilize temporaries by calling the tuple constructor:*" It's not clear what you're referring to here, or how what `make_tuple` does is in *any way* more optimal than your first option.

Comment: @LorahAttkins - Compiler optimizers can do amazing things these days.  Code you think is inefficient turns out it isn't, all due to compilers eliminating unnecessary copies.  This means you build your program with optimizations turned on, and see if all of your fears are indeed there.

Comment: @NicolBolas I have a class and it has two members. I also have two temporaries of the same type as these members. How should I construct my class so that I'll make the best use of the objects I already have? I've been reading on direct, copy, list, aggregate and list initialization and I still can't figure this out (it seems that copying is never out of the table as far as standard guarantees go). If you can elaborate on an **answer** please, please, please do so.

Comment: As a side note, you can actually check if your types have a move constructor: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible

Comment: @LorahAttkins "*it seems that copying is never out of the table as far as standard  guarantees go*" I guess that's the part I don't understand; why do you think it matters if copying is on or off the table? You talk about "utilize temporaries" but copying "utilize temporaries" just as much as moving. I get the impression that there's something about the concept of movement in C++ that you're not understanding.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh there's plenty about the concept of movement that eludes me. By "utilize" I mean "use the objects themselves" and by copying not being on the table I mean this (utilization) should happen not by relying on some compiler dependent optimization but on standard guarantees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already optimal:

```
Comp(T&& t, U&& u)
: t_m(std::move(t))
, u_m(std::move(u))
{ }
```

If `T` has a move constructor, this'll be a move. If it doesn't, this'll be a copy - but then there's no way around making a copy somewhere. And it isn't copyable, then the whole question is moot.

Of course this only works for rvalues, so you'd want something for lvalues too. That unfortunately gets a little complicated:

```
template <class Tx, class Ux, 
    class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<std::decay_t<Tx>*, T*>::value &&
                             std::is_convertible<std::decay_t<Ux>*, U*>::value>>
Comp(Tx&& t, Ux&& u)
: t_m(std::forward<Tx>(t))
, u_m(std::forward<Ux>(u))
{ }
```

Here we want to allow deduction of `Tx` such that it's either `T`, `T&`, or `D`, `D&` where `D` derives from `T`. `std::decay` drops the reference and `is_convertible` for pointers checks if it's derived.

Okay, can we do better? Not really. This is either going to do 1 move or 1 copy for each member. But what if we want to construct them in place? That we should be able to allow for:

```
template <class... TArgs, class... UArgs,
    class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, TArgs...>::value &&
                             std::is_constructible<U, UArgs...>::value>>
Comp(std::piecewise_construct_t pc, std::tuple<TArgs...> const& t, std::tuple<UArgs...> const& u)
: Comp(t, u, std::index_sequence_for<TArgs...>{}, std::index_sequence_for<UArgs...>{})
{ }

private:
template <class TTuple, class UTuple, size_t... Is, size_t... Js>
Comp(TTuple const& t, UTuple const& u, std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::index_sequence<Js...> )
: t_m(std::get<Is>(t)...)
, u_m(std::get<Js>(u)...)
{ }
```

With this potentially we can avoid any kind of copy or move at all by just constructing in-place. Whether or not this is beneficial depends on your usage of `Comp`.

Comment: Great! On a side note, is piecewise construction supported for `std::tuple` now ? (I haven't heard of this before and while searching I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11846634/4224575))

Answer (score 1):

Your proposition with the move constructor seems to be the best approach.

As you deal with temporary objects, the best thing to do (and the most optimized) is to move the parameters in the members. But as you said maybe the move constructors may not exist.

If there is only one parameter it is easy to check if it is move constructible and move it and copy it otherwise. You can use `std::enable_if` with `std::is_move_constructible`.

But with more than 1 parameter, you have to check all the combinations. For instance for 2 parameters you have to have 4 constructors that do: copy/copy, move/copy, copy/move and move/move. So it is not really scalable and then it is more  suitable to copy the parameters.

With the aggregate initialization the parameters are copy not move.