# What is the rationale behind decltype behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, decltype, type-deduction

As I understood in C++11 `decltype(expression)` is used to deduce the exact same type of the given expression. But when the expression is put into parentheses itself, then the deduces type is *lvalue reference* to the expression type. For example:

```
int x;
decltype(x) y = x;
```

is equivalent to `int y = x;` but,

```
int x;
decltype((x)) y = x;
```

is equivalent to `int& y = x;`.

Respectively

```
 decltype(auto) f1()
 {
   int x = 0;
   return x; // decltype(x) is int, so f1 returns int
 }
```

but

```
 decltype(auto) f2()
 {
   int x = 0;
   return (x); // decltype((x)) is int&, so f2 returns int&
 }
```

What is the rationale for this behavior to be chose by the standard committee?

**Afterwords:**

Now I observed that at least in the case of **GCC 6.2** implementation when the expression in the parentheses is more complex for example `decltype((x + x))` the deduced type is `T`, but not `T&`. This is even more confusing. I don't know whether this behavior is standard.

Comment: Maybe this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241614/in-c-what-expressions-yield-a-reference-type-when-decltype-is-applied-to-them

Comment: Well, they needed SOME way to make decltype be able to produce a ref. So they just rolled the random syntax dice to come up with parentheses.

Comment: @BorislavStanimirov, well than the question is when does `decltype` *need* to produce a (lvalue) ref? There are ways to explicitly make it a ref if we need one.

Comment: @StoryTeller You'd need it for functions returning `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: @TartanLlama, `decltype(auto)` came around `c++14`, while the `decltype` specification was like this since `c++11`, it doesn't seem like the reason to me.

Comment: @StoryTeller I know, it was just an observation for why it can be useful now :)

Comment: This feels the natural way to me, to be honest. `decltype(identifier)` is the type of the identifier. If it's a non id-expression instead, it's T& if it's a lvalue, because that's how C++ speaks about "lvalues designating something else"

Comment: It's obvious that they wanted people to stop randomly parenthesizing their `return` expressions.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

They wanted a way to get the type of declaration of an identifier.

They also wanted a way to get the type of an expression, including information about if it is a temporary or not.

`decltype(x)` gives the declared type of the identifier `x`.  If you pass `decltype` something that is not an identifier, it determines the type, then appends `&` for lvalues, `&&` for xvalues, and nothing for prvalues.

Conceptually you can think of it as the difference between the type of a variable and the type of an expression.  But that is not quite how the standard describes it.

They could have used two different keywords to mean these two things.  They did not.

Comment: But when I give something that is not an identifier like `decltype(x + 1)` or `decltype((x + 1))` in both cases the deduced type is `int`, but not `int&` nor more logical `int&&` (tested with **GCC 6.2** and **boost::type_index** library). Why?

Comment: @bobeff Because `x+1` is a prvalue?

Comment: @bobeff Note that `decltype(x + 1)` will always be identical to `decltype((x + 1))` no matter what the type of `x` is and how `operator+` may be overloaded for it. The reason is that `x+1` is an expression, therefore adding parentheses around it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Columbo. Maybe yes. From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category): _A prvalue cannot be polymorphic: the dynamic type of the object it identifies is always the type of the expression._

Comment: `decltype` doesn't necessarily give you the dynamic type of an object, even when you say `decltype(x)`. The actual type of an *object* referred to by `x` (when `x` is a `foo.bar`) may not be known at compile time. In such cases, `decltype` is supposed to yield the declared type of the member that `x` refers to (in other words, when we have the choice between the entity kinds "class member" and "object", we have to choose "class member"). That's a bit ambiguous in the spec, and the disambiguation relies on prior knowledge/expertise with the language and common sense.

Answer (score 25):

There is some need for discriminating between an entity and an expression.

Consider the following question:

> How long is Mississippi?

There are two answers to this question:

1. Mississippi is 2,320 miles long.
2. Mississippi is 11 letters long.

Similarly when you ask about the type of `x`, and `x` is an identifier, it is not clear whether you mean the type that was used to declare that identifier (i.e. the type associated with the name `x`), or the type of the expression consisting of the sole mentioning of that identifier. In fact there could be two different keywords (e.g. `entity_type` and `expr_type`) instead of a single overloaded `decltype`. For some reason, the committee chose to overload `decltype` for those two different uses.

Answer (score 18):

From one of the authors of the `decltype` proposal, J. Jarvi:

> It’s been a while, but here’s what I (think I) remember:
>
> Two separate keywords for differentiating these two kinds of semantics
>   was never considered. (Introducing new keywords is not done lightly).
>
> As to the change of the semantics of `decltype((x))`, discussion in the
>   core working group converged to treating `(x)` as an expression, rather
>   than an identifier, which perhaps is more  “internally consistent”
>   with the language rules.
>
> People were aware that this could potentially be confusing in some
>   cases, but the consensus (while perhaps not everyone’s preference) was
>   eventually to be consistent with the standard’s prior definition of
>   what is an identifier and what is an expression.
>
> The example you link to [this question's example] is indeed surprising. At the time, deducing a
>   function’s return type from its return expression using `decltype(auto)`
>   was not yet part of the language, so I don’t think this particular use
>   case was on anyone’s radar.