# Returning a generic lambda expression from a function causes compiler warnings if an explicit return type is given

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, c++14, generic-lambda

I have a function whose return type is a simple generic lambda expression. (The lambda returned by this function is eventually passed as an argument to STL algorithms like `std::transform()` or `std::accumulate()`.)

When the lambda does not have an explicit return type, the compiler emits no warnings:

```
inline auto AccumulateInto() {
    return [](const auto& src, const auto& dst) {return dst + src; };
}
```

When the lambda has an explicit return type specified:

```
inline auto AccumulateInto() {
    return [](const auto& src, const auto& dst) -> decltype(dst) {return dst + src; };
}
```

both compilers emit these similar warnings:

**GCC**: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]

**MSVC**: returning address of a local variable or temporary

Should this warning be heeded because it indicates a shortcoming in the approach (possible undefined behavior!) and should be refactored? or are they "noise"?

I can't determine why specifying the return type explicitly would cause the returned expression to be a "temporary" when it wouldn't be otherwise.  Please explain, thanks!

**EDIT** (to add more context):

The desire to use `auto` arguments to the lambda is that `src` and `dst` might be different types (e.g. one is `std::uint8_t` and one is `std::uint_16t`), but I want the return to ALWAYS be the same type as the `dst` argument, regardless of the type of `src`.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241614/what-expressions-yield-a-reference-type-when-decltype-is-applied-to-them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that `decltype(dst)` is `auto const &` (where you can see `auto` as a template type`, so the lambda return a **reference** (I repeat: a **reference**) to a constant object.

The problem is that is a reference to

```
dst + src
```

that is: a reference to a temporary value, the temporary object created from the operation `dst + src`, that doesn't exist anymore when the lambda conclude the execution.

A possible solution: remove `-> decltype(dst)` or change it to `-> decltype(dst+src)`, so you return a value, not a reference.

Another way (require more typewriting in this case but can be prefereble in more complex cases) could be remove the reference part from the type returned from `decltype()`.

So

```
-> std::remove_reference_t<decltype(dst)>
```

or, as suggested by Jarod42, also

```
-> std::decay_t<decltype(dst)>
```

If the type of `dst` support the unary operator `+` (returning the same type of `dst`), another simple solution can be

```
-> decltype(+dst)
```

This way, `+dst` is an expression, not a variable, so `decltype(+dst)` isn't a reference anymore.

Comment: `std::decay_t` might be an alternative ( depending of OP' needs).

Comment: @Jarod42 - Right: the `decltype()` of the sum is a possible solution, not the solution. Answer improved to stress this point.

Comment: Thank you max66 and Jarod42.  I added some additional context in the original post.

Comment: @Jarod42 - D'Oh! I have to sleep more. Thanks.

Comment: The compiler warning isn't specific, so I assumed the return of the enclosing AccumulateInto() function was problematic, but from your explanations it seems like it's actually the return type of the enclosed lambda expression which is problematic... is this correct?

Comment: @NKatUT - Yes and no: isn't a problem of lambda but a problem regarding all function/functional and (from C++14) the deduction for `auto` as return type. In your first example, the lambda return `dst + src` so is equivalent adding `-> decltype(dst + src)`. When you write `-> decltype(dst)` you impose a different type (the type from `dst + src` can be different from the type of `dst`) and you add a `const` and a `reference.

Comment: @NKatUT - Anyway: the `std::remove_reference_t`/`std::decay_t` solution should works with your additional requirements; I've also added another possible solution (`-> decltype(+dst)` but is less generic because require that the type of `dst` support the unary operator `+`; should works also `-> decltype(dst+dst)` if the binary operator `+` is supported.

Comment: Ahh - so if I pass a "uint16_t" as the dst argument, the result of the decltype(dst) is actually a "const uint16_t&" rather than just "uint16_t", since that is how the lamdba's argument inputs it?  Thus, the std::remove_reference<> approach converts the explicit return value of the lambda back to "const uint16_t" without the reference.  Correct?

Comment: @NKatUT - Almost correct: since that is how the C++ works deducing the returned type for function with `auto` as return type (a lamba is (contains) implicitly a function with an `auto` return type, if you don't explicit it with trailing return type. And `std::remove_reference<>` approach converts the deduced return **type** removing the reference, if present.

Comment: Please don't remove the c++ tag from C++ questions. It's preferable to remove any other tag instead if the limit of 5 is already reached.